# Custom parameters from PipelineOptions

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a CustomSource and CustomSink. These Source and Sink require specific parameters like from where the data has to be read and where the result has to be written.

I want to pass these parameters as args to PipelineOption. How to get these parameter from PipelineOption?

Is writing my own Option extending PipelineOption the only way?

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create your own options you first extend the PipelineOptions interface:

```
public static interface Options extends PipelineOptions {
    String getInput();
    void setInput(String value);

    String getOutput();
    void setOutput(String value);
}
```

Then when creating your PipelineOptions you do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
     ...
}
```

When you want to retrieve your options:

```
Options options = pipeline.getOptions().as(Options.class);
options.getInput();
```

You can also take a look at the word count example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/WordCount.java).

Comment: However, Samuel - please note that you should prefer to use the PipelineOptions only when constructing the pipeline, instead of extracting your source/sink parameters out of it at runtime. Your Source or Sink class should be a completely self-contained description of where to read from or where to write to - PipelineOptions should, at most, help with pipeline-global things like credentials. Otherwise, e.g. if you put a filename into PipelineOptions, and want to read two different files from your pipeline, you'd be out of luck.

Comment: So there is no other way to write apart from extending PipelineOption? But as Eugene Kirpichov commented, I will try to make the Source and Sink as self contained. Thanks, Sam